# How to compute singular points on a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $H$ be the variety defined by $H = \{(x, y, z, t)\in \mathbb{C}^4: xy = z^2 + t^2\}$. How to compute all singular points on $H$? Thank you very much.

My partial solution: it seems that $(x,y,z,t)=(0,0,0,0)$ is a singular point. Are there other singular points? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the Jacobian criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mariano said in the comments, there is something called the Jacobian criterion. Basically one looks at where the minors of the Jacobian matrix of the ideal defining the variety vanishes. You can Google it to get a more accurate definition.

In this case however, the variety is defined by the single equation $f=xy-z^2-t^2=0$. It can be seen that this is singular exactly where $\nabla f=f=0$, that is, where all partial derivatives vanish **and** $f$ vanish.

In this case the partial derivatives are $f_x=y, f_y=x, f_z=-2z$ and $f_t=-2t$, so the only singular point is the origin.